# Rudin - Principles of math analysis, ex. 15 chapt. 5

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification

$\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}$
Suppose $a \in \RR, D = (a,+\infty), f : D \rightarrow \RR$ differentiable two times on its domain, $M_0, M_1, M_2 \in \RR : |f(x)| \leq M_0, |f'(x)| \leq M_1, |f''(x)| \leq M_2, \forall x \in D$. Prove that $M_1^2 \leq 4 M_0 M_2$.

For Taylor theorem, if I choose $x_0 \in D$ there exists $\xi \in D $ s.t. $ \forall x \in D$,

$$
  -M_1  \leq f'(x) = f'(x_0) + f''(\xi)(x-x_0) \leq M_1 + M_2(x-x_0)
$$

But if I choose $x - x_0 =  4 M_0 - \dfrac{2M_1}{M_2} - M_1 ^2 $ ($x, x_0 \in D$ since I can shift $x, x_0$ by an arbitrary constant without changing their difference) I obtain the thesis.

Does this proof make sense? Is there any flaw?

---

Comment: Sorry to bump this question, but what happens if f is not bounded? This statement becomes false, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Taylor's formula you have $$
f(x+2h)=f(x)+2hf'(x)+2h^{2}f''(w)$$ with $x<w<x+2h$.

Rewrite this as $$f'(x)=\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x)}{2h}-hf''(w)$$

Take absolute values we then have

$$M_{1}<2M_{0}/2h+hM_{2}$$

But the function $g(h)=M_{0}/h+hM_{2}$ obtains maximum at $M_{2}=M_{0}/h^{2}$. This force $h^{2}=\frac{M_{0}}{M_{2}}$. And the maximum is obtained at $2\sqrt{M_{0}M_{2}}$.

Comment: Yes, this is true, and I have already seen this proof. My question was about the way I tried to solve the problem choosing $ x - x_0 =  4 M_0 - \dfrac{2M_1}{M_2} - M_1 ^2$. Does it makes sense? Or why it shouldn't?

Comment: The maximum may not be obtained, but the inequality would hold nevertheless.