# Application of Taylor's theorem, Baby Rudin 5.15

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

Suppose a ∈ R1, f is a twice-differentiable real function on (a,∞),
and M0, M1, M2 are the least upper bounds of $|f(x)|, |f'(x)|, |f''(x)|,$
respectively, on $(a, ∞)$.

Prove that $M_1^2 ≤ 4M_0M_2$.

Hint:  If $h > 0,$ Taylor’s theorem shows that
$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2h}
[f(x + 2h) − f(x)] − hf''(ξ)$
for some $ξ ∈ (x, x + 2h). $ . . .

---

My question is how to apply Taylor's theorem so that we get 
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2h} [f(x + 2h) − f(x)] − hf''(ξ)$$
for some $ξ ∈ (x, x + 2h).$

Comment: I use $x$ and $y$ in place of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ -- easier to type.

Comment: Correct Taylor: $f(\beta) = f(\alpha) + f'(\alpha)(\beta - \alpha) + \ldots$, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any points in the domain where you want to bound $f'$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that $(\sup_{x\in R}|f'(x)|)^2\leq 4\sup_{x\in R}|f(x)|\cdot\sup_{x\in R}|f''(x)|$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019774/proving-that-sup-x-in-rfx2-leq-4-sup-x-in-rfx-cdot-sup-x-in-r)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/326684 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24M_1%5E2%20%5Cle%204M_0M_2%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x$ and $y$, $f(y) = f(x) + f'(x)(y-x) + \frac{1}{2} f''(\xi)(y-x)^2,$ is  the Taylor approximation where $\xi$ is some point in between $x$ and $y$.

Thus,

$$f'(x)(y-x) = f(y) - f(x) - \frac{1}{2}f''(\xi)(y-x)^2.$$

If $|f(x)| \leqslant M_0$ and $|f''(x)| \leqslant M_2$ are bounds, then

$$|f'(x)| \leqslant \frac{|f(x)| + |f(y)|}{|y-x|} + \frac{1}{2} |f''(\xi)| |y-x| \leqslant \frac{2M_0}{|x-y|}+ \frac{M_2}{2}|x-y|.$$

Now notice that

$$\min_{0 < z < \infty} \left(\frac{2M_0}{z} + \frac{M_2z}{2}\right)= 2 \sqrt{M_0M_2}$$

You should be able to finish from here.

Comment: How do you know that is the minima?

Comment: $|f'(x)|$ is less than $2M_0/|x-y| + M_2|x-y|/2$ no matter what we pick for $y$.

Comment: So $|x-y|$ can range in $(0,\infty)$ and $|f'(x)|$ must be less than the greatest lower bound.

Comment: Solve for the minimum of that expression $(2M_0/z + M_2z/2)$ by taking the derivative and setting it equal to $0$. The minimum is at $z = 2\sqrt{M_2/M_0}$.

Comment: I now understand that, but does it matter that it is the min? Could we just choose $|x−y| = \sqrt { 2M_2/M_0} $?

Comment: We could put any positive value in for $|y-x|$ and it would be an upper bound for all $|f’(x)|$ but we didn’t know that until we proved it.  Also we now know that the specific value you choose in your comment gives us the least upper bound for the derivative.